# Couchbase with core data sync does not support for model versions

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, couchbase-lite

I am trying to sync the database (using core data) using CBLIncrementalStore. In managedObjectModel i am adding updateManagedObjectModel method. My data model has 7 versions, every time app is started i get crash on line entity.properties = properties;

But when there is only one version it is working fine. So does couch base not support the core data model versions ?

Answer (score 0):

we are investigating this issue and will continue to add and comment on this question [on our GitHub repo](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios/issues/398)